# TFS BuildProcessTemplate - Switch<T> always seems to choose Default option

Tags: xaml, tfs, build-process, default, switch-statement

I'm attempting to get a build process template to switch build tools based on the *project file extension* (specifically, I'm trying to build some Sandcastle and SqlSpec documentation projects without using MSBuild 4.0).  I'm trying to use the `Switch<T>` construct to choose the tool by examining the project's file extension.

**For some reason, however, the `Switch<T>` construct always executes the Default option.**  I've configured it so that a `Switch<String>` checks the variable I created to hold the project extension against variables to which I've assigned my documentation extensions (i.e.: `localProjectExtension` against `sandcastleProjectExtension` and `sqlSpecProjectExtension`).  Yet, no matter what I do, the Default case, in which MSBuild 4.0 will run, always executes.  I've tried printing out the extensions I'm parsing out of the file name just to make sure they look good, and they do.  I've been at this for hours, and I'm kind of stumped.

Does this sound like a familiar problem to anyone?  Would an XAML block help?

Comment: I've not hit this problem myself but have spent some time previously rooting around in BuildProcessTemplates - can you please post the xaml (ideally including the mechanism you used to inspect your variable to make sure it's set at the appropriate time) and I'll see if I can help at all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you typed the values at case with "'s.
The switch already knows, that you are going to type a string, so you DONOT type the “’s. That’s why you possibly execute always the default option.

He has done a similar task, as you wanted to do:
http://donovanbrown.com/post/I-need-to-build-a-project-that-is-not-supported-by-MSBuild.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the cases without the brackets... Instead of "2010" just use 2010